What counts as a strike for Zeus's Static Shock Boon?
Zeus's Static Shock boon has the description "After you enter a Location, Prime 50 Magick to make your strikes emit chain-lightning." I can't tell if this meant the boon would buff lightning strikes from other Zeus Boons, which I had none of a the time, or if it would cause chain-lightning any time I hit an enemy with an attack.
What counts as a strike for Zeus's Static Shock Boon?


In that case, we're talking about actual strikes, which is a word encapsulating your normal attacks and all specials. Hitting an enemy with any of these will trigger the chain lightning attack, damaging the targeted enemy, and then bouncing to close enemies.

Do Boon-given Casts like Poseidon's Wave count too?
